# How to redirect user to url React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect

I have a question that sounds quite simple but I just can't find a solution. I have tried multiple answers on similar questions for both standard JS and specifically for React, but I can't seem to find something that works.

I want to redirect my users to my login screen when they navigate to the website without being logged in. What is a working statement for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you specify your setup, this question is opnion-based.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+redirect+user+to+url+React&oq=How+to+redirect+user+to+url+React&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 3):

If you use something like [React Router: Declarative Routing for React.js](https://reactrouter.com/), which is the right way to do redirects, you can use [`Redirect`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect) API in two ways:

- Using the `<Redirect to="" />`
- Using a higher order function [`withRouter()`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)

---

For using `<Redirect to="" />`, all you need to do is, with a condition or inside the component, use:

```js
<Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />
{/* Or in your case... */}
<Route exact path="/">
  {loggedIn ? <Redirect to="/dashboard" /> : <PublicHomePage />}
</Route>
```

Using [`withRouter()`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter):

```js
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    // Check user logged in and redirect somewhere.
    if (loggedIn) {
      // Something like this.
      location.replace("/dashboard");
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;
    return <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>;
  }
}

// Create a new component that is "connected" (to borrow redux
// terminology) to the router.
const App = withRouter(App);
```

Comment: `location.push` isn't a redirect, it should be `location.replace`. Also, the `render` lifecycle function is a pure function, so there shouldn't be the side-effect of imperative navigation, this should be done in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

Comment: @DrewReese I'll update. Thanks. I have been using this all in my app. Should I also update in my client apps too? What's the bad thing that might happen here?

Comment: @DrewReese Updated like you said, using `componentDidMount` lifecycle method

Answer (score 0):

Every route for your app has to be wrapped in a HOC inside which will check whether the user is authenticated or not in `componentDidMount`.
If not authenticated, you redirect to the login screen.

In case, your app support token for authentication:
In the `componentDidMount` of the HOC, you could check if the token cached in some browser storage is still valid or not, and based on the validity you decide to redirect to the login screen

**What I prefer**:

I find, using `Redirect` of `react-router-dom` to be more declarative. Check the usage here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect

Comment: The problem is not with checking whether the user is authenticated, that works. I just can't seem to find a working statement for redirecting

Comment: Oh got it!. Then, @Praveen 's answer is what you need

Comment: Different libraries provide different API for redirection

Comment: If using react-router-dom, then using `<Redirect />` is your answer

Comment: Check this out - https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect

Answer (score -1):

Just add this code
`window.location.replace('new url')`
Whenever this line gets executed the window will be replaced to the new defined URL! :D

Comment: This is supposed to be React SPA, not normal HTML & JavaScript.

Answer (score -2):

```
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';

firebase.initializeApp({
  //your key from firebase
})

const [user] = useAuthState(auth); 

<section>
      {user ? <ChatRoom /> : <SignIn />}
</section>
```