# How to Redirect to a route after identifying a screen size of the browser in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app developed only for larger screens (mobile devices are excluded). I have created a different component to show if the app is opened by a mobile device and a route is also created. To trigger the redirection, I have created a function inside the index.js file. **The problem is, the function fails to return the Redirection when I open the app on the mobile phone**.

**index.js**

```
import { Front, MobileComponent } from './pages';

  const MobileRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => {
      return <Component {...props} />
    }}
    />
  )
  
  function checkMobile() {
    if (window.screen.width < 768) {
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/mobile' }} />
    }
  }
  
  checkMobile();
  
  render(
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Front} />
              <MobileRoute path="/mobile" component={MobileComponent} />
            </Switch>
            <ToastMessage />
            <GlobalHandler />
          </BrowserRouter>
    ,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

**MobileComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class MobileComponent extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="mobileComponentMain">
                <div className="mobileComponentInner">
                    <img src="/static/images/site/newlogo_temp.jpeg" alt="newlogo" className="mobileComponentLogo" />
                    <div className="mobileComponentText">
                        <span>Open Home mobile app is coming soon!</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(MobileComponent);
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect user to url React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872942/how-to-redirect-user-to-url-react)

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman NO!

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Sorry I didn't mean to shout at all. Do you have any answers to the question?

Comment: No worries and no offence taken, I have answered it and solved it too.

Comment: David, does the answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this logic:

```js
  function checkMobile() {
    if (window.screen.width < 768) {
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/mobile' }} />
    }
  }
  
  checkMobile();
```

This doesn't execute inside the `render()` code, which is needed to render the `<Redirect />`. Even if it executes, you return the tag but there's no way it is gonna go into the rendering place.

So the best way to do is, set a state:

```js
  function checkMobile() {
    if (window.screen.width < 768) {
      this.setState({
        redirect: <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/mobile' }} />
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    checkMobile();
  }
```

And in the `render()` function:

```js
render() {
  return (
    {this.state.redirect}
    {/* Other codes follow */}
  );
}
```

By default, you can either initialise `redirect` in state to be `null` or not needed as it will not cause any harm. If it's set, then the `<Redirect />` tag will be rendered, redirecting the user.

Comment: That means I need to convert the whole component into a Class right?

Comment: @DavidJohns Not needed. If it's a functional component, can you wrap it on `withRouter(FuncComponent)`? If that's possible, then you can use `props.history.push("/mobile")` inside the function.

Comment: I actually tried `props.history.push("/mobile")` In my index.js which I mentioned in the code, But here props are undefined. I think the component is not either a functional component

Comment: @DavidJohns I just mentioned above, use `withRouter(FuncComponent)` and `const FuncComponent = (props) => { ... }`.

Comment: @DavidJohns Before anything. Your code is totally wrong. Can you show the full code if that's not the full code on the question, please? There's no `render()` function in a Functional Component.

Comment: Kumar This is the Primer React Template and I have put the full index.js file code here except import modules. And this is working nicely except the feature which has the issue mentioned

Comment: @DavidJohns Oh yes, but I got confused when you have `render()` function and no class component.